# C++ set stack pointer

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

In my C++ / C project I want to set the *stack pointer* equal to the *base pointer*... Intuitively I would use something like this:

```
asm volatile(
    "movl %%ebp %%esp"
);
```

However, when I execute this, I get this error message:

```
Error: bad register name `%%ebp %%esp'
```

I use gcc / g++ version 4.9.1 compiler.

I dont know whether I need to set specific g++ or gcc flag though... There should be a way to manipulate the `esp` and `ebp` registers but I just don't know the right way to do it.

Doe anybody know how to manipulate these two registers in c++? Maybe I should do it with hexed OP codes?

Comment: a comma between `%%ebp` and `%%esp` is missing

Comment: You probably want `movl %%ebp, %%esp`. But don't do that unless you create a "naked" function, as your code will conflict with the stack frame setup which is already done automagically by the compiler.

Comment: Also, in simple asm, you don't need to double `%`. What you are trying to do is a very bad idea though and sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti C++, but it also applies to C since inline assembler syntax is the same there... I guess...
@Neroku You are right , but i still get " Error: bad register name `%%ebp' "
@DanielKamilKozar What is a naked function? Currently I am creating a C++ Interceptor agent for my java application...

Comment: @Jester I know its a bit hacky, but I do not see any other better solution...

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976035/c-forward-function-call)

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089692/jni-intercepting-native-methods-outputs)

Comment: @AksimElnik Don't _hack_ please! If you don't see a _better solution_ there's probably a problem with your overall design.

Comment: why's this downvoted? is there an automatism that 'C' tagged Questions start with a -3 malus or something?

Comment: @Tommylee2k man this question had -10 in the beginning hahah)))

Comment: _"C++, but it also applies to C since inline assembler syntax is the same there..."_ Not a sufficient reason to language-tag-spam. Tag the language you're actually using, and nothing else.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar :When _GCC_ has an x86 target the `naked` function attribute isn't available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using [GNU C ***Basic*** Asm syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) (no input/output/clobber constraints), so `%` is not special and therefore, it shouldn't be escaped.

It's only in *Extended Asm* (with constraints) that `%` needs to be escaped to end up with a single `%` in front of hard-coded register names in the compiler's asm output ([as required in AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250270/224132)).

You also have to separate the operands with a comma:

```
asm volatile(
    "movl %ebp, %esp"
);
```

`asm` statements with no output operands are implicitly volatile, but it doesn't hurt to write an explicit `volatile`.

Note, however, that putting this statement inside a function will likely interfere with the way the compiler handles the *stack frame*.

Comment: Why do I need double '%' in front of eax or ebx , but only single in front of ebp and esp??? And yeah, thank you, it worked :)

Comment: @AksimElnik I think you only need the double `%` if a colon (`:`) comes after the assembly string

Comment: Ahh, makes sence... Thank you

Comment: Your inline assembly takes no parameters, therefore there is no reason to escape the registers (because there are no `%1`, `%2`, ...).

Comment: @AksimElnik: GNU C basic (no operands) vs. extended (with operand) asm has other differences.  For example, Basic asm statements are implicitly `volatile` (but so are Extended asm statements with no output operands).  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html

Comment: @眠りネロク: you should probably say that putting this statement inside a function will not be useful, and will just step on the compiler's toes (as [Jester pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109992/c-set-stack-pointer#comment75239309_44109992).)  I already expanded on your answer to explain why, but adding that too would be going too far in putting words in your mouth, I think.  Especially since the question is asking "how to manipulate these two registers in C++".